# No puedo enviar correos a gmail desde mi sistema hecho en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un sistema desarrollado en laravel, desde el cual estoy enviando algunas notificaciones por correo, son correos empresariales (ej= juanperez@empresa.com.mx) y no había tenido ningún problema. recientemente me surgió la necesidad de notificar a los usuarios, pero si ingresan correos de GMIL, HOTMAIL y otros personales me manda el siguiente error:

Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "554", with message "554 5.7.1 alguncorreo@gmail.com: **Relay access denied**".

para enviar los correos utilizo el servicio: sparkpost

por que pasa esto? que puedo hacer para solucionarlo?
Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Creo que el problema lo tienes en el remitente, que al ser `alguncorreo@gmail.com` y no estar enviandolo con los servidores de correo de gmail, se creen que quieres hacer algun tipo de relay.  Si usas un remitente de gmail prueba usando el propio gmail como servidor de salida, o bien cambia el remitente a uno que realmente esté bien configurado para el servidor desde el cual mandas esos emails.

Comment: ¿Tienes el ssl activo? los servidores de gmail tengo entendido que solo responden si lo tienes activo, ademas de alguna condicion adicional

Comment: Si estás usando `smtp.sparkpostmail.com`, buscando en el sitio de ellos dice que puedes estár conectándote sin STARTTLS/SSL (no es lo mismo que TLS). https://support.sparkpost.com/docs/faq/relaying-denied-error. Si efecta solamente a algunos destinatarios entonces es un problema de Sparkpost, quizás porque tienen mal configuradas sus cabeceras DKIM o DMARK. Pero eso no sólo sería inusual si es supuestamente lo que mejor saben hacer. (y está fuera de tu control)